# Improving screenshare quality in Google Meet?

Tags: sharing, google-meet, screencasts

I have been struggling with this for the past two months. The quality of my screensharing in Google Meet is really unacceptable for my business use (demos, training, reviewing google sheets, etc). Our entire team (40ish people) use Meet daily and I am the only one with this problem (shown below). I have searched and searched and searched for answers on this, and the only answers I can find from Google have to do with camera/video sharing and the "Quality" setting that is easy to find and change. My issue tends to be sharing Google Chrome tabs, although the problem is even WORSE with MS Edge. At this point I am thinking it could be related to my unique desktop configuration:

- Nvidia 1080 Ti
- 3 x 31.5" monitors
- Nvidia Surround combines into a single "display" of 7800 x 1440 resolution

However I am clearly NOT trying to share my entire desktop. But given the overall size of my display resolution, maybe the Google code is trying to overly compress for some reason?
**Help me please!** :)

[image]

Comment: This is my teams' big sticking point preventing us from using Meet over Zoom.  When screen sharing we have problems reading code on customers monitors and vice versa. Zoom doesn't appear to have this problem.  I don't think it's a tech problem or a lack of features it's most likely Google aggressively-optimizing the video feed in order to decrease bandwidth.